# How human placental lactogen (hPL) is associated with insulin resistance in pregnancy?

Tags: obstetrics, endocrinology

I am unable to understand the molecular mechanism of hPL induced insulin resistance. Sharing of relevant article/text would be of immense help.

Answer (score -2):

hPL elevates insulin resistance due to it causes free fatty acid consumption. With this way, the fetus can consump the mother's glucose.

Source: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/human-placental-lactogen

Comment: But how does that explain insulin resistance? What I meant to ask is the molecular mechanism underlying hPL induced insulin resistance.